# entities JPA Hibernate errors

Tags: jakarta-ee

Here is some line of my program:
 I use entities JPA Hibernate in my JEE program.

Please, how can resolve these errors ?

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-196]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:336)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:162)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
... 29 more
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: As it says: you have the wrong user name or password set

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have to modify this: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:h2:~/target/db"/>
  ? Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add username and password:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
```